# What should we do when receives timeout error during PubNub.subscribe() to channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pubnub

I'm having a PubNub service running on the back end based on Node.js to handle device token registration, and also subscribing the devices to a specific channel. After a while watching the log stream, I noticed there is a lot of timeout errors during subscribing the devices.

The error logged:

```
error: Failed to subscribe the clients { message: 'timeout' }
error: Failed to subscribe the clients { message: 'timeout' }
error: Failed to subscribe the clients { message: 'timeout' }
error: Failed to subscribe the clients { message: 'timeout' }
error: Failed to subscribe the clients { message: 'timeout' }
error: Failed to subscribe the clients { message: 'timeout' }
error: Failed to subscribe the clients { message: 'timeout' }
```

The code snippet that running the subscribing process:

```
...
subscribe: function (channelId) {
    pubnub.subscribe({
      channel: channelId,
      message: function (message, env, channel) {
        sails.log.info('new message received > ', message);
      },
      error: function (error) {
        sails.log.error('Failed to subscribe the clients', error);
      }
    });
  },
...
```

According to [the API doc](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference#subscribe) by default a client will attempt to reconnect after exceeding a 320 second connection timeout. My understanding is the client (PubNub SDK for Node.js) will reconnect when the subscribing is timeout, not sure if this true or not.

If its not, do I need to implement another code to handle this subscribe timeout error?

Side notes:

1. The current implementation is not using any Presence features provided by PubNub, so this timeout obviously not related to Presence.

Comment: I will follow up with you in your private support ticket and provide full answer here when we reach a resolution.